# HTML shows � symbol when rendered on Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, sharepoint, encoding

I created a .HTML file in SharePoint Document library using JSOM. when I view the HTML file in google chrome it shows � symbol at start of each tag.
below are the codes that I used to create HTML file

```
var uploadedDocument;
function uploadFile(arrayBuffer, fileName,UploadclientContext,oList)  
{  
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);  
        var i, length, out = '';  
        for (i = 0, length = bytes.length; i < length; i += 1)  
        {  
            out += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);  
        }  
        var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();  
        createInfo.set_url(fileName);  
        createInfo.set_overwrite(true);

        createInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());  
        fileContent =out; 
        for (var i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++)   
        {  
            createInfo.get_content().append(fileContent.charCodeAt(i));  
        } 
         uploadedDocument = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(createInfo)  

        UploadclientContext.load(uploadedDocument);  
        UploadclientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess(fileName), QueryFailure);  
}
```

[this is HTML is get in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGOo0.png)

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post the actual generated HTML so it can be inspected?

Comment: @Stevangelista here is the generated HTML 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGOo0.png